# WFP binding ViewModel to listbox nested in another listbox, both listboxes using DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

I am working on an app in C# using WPF 4.0 and Caliburn Micro. I need to bind a ViewModel to a listbox which is one of the controls in a DataTemplate. This DataTemplate is used as ItemTemplate in an outer listbox and... No, I guess that is not very clear.

Let me try to explain what I need to do using an example with a hotel with several rooms, where each room has several guests.

The hotel screen has a listbox named Rooms which is bound to an ObservableCollection also named Rooms containing RoomViewModel items. The Rooms listbox has an ItemTemplate named RoomTemplate, looking like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Rooms" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource RoomTemplate}"/>
```

With RoomTemplate looking something like this (highly simplified):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RoomTemplate">
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock x:Name="RoomDescription" Text="{Binding Path=RoomDescr}" />
        <ListBox x:Name="Guests" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource GuestTemplate}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

RoomViewModel contains an ObservableCollection named Guests containing GuestViewModel items. RoomTemplate contains a listbox named Guests that should display the GuestViewModel items in the Guests collection. The GuestTemplate would contain several TextBlocks that needs bindings to the GuestViewModels.

The first binding for listbox Rooms to collection Rooms is handled by CM's conventions binder and works just fine. My problem is the second binding for listbox Guests in the GuestTemplate. How can I bind it to the Guest items in the RoomViewModels contained in Rooms collection?

Comment: OK, I have solved it. Solution was ItemsSource="{Binding Guests}", which I had already tried, but I had another error in my code so it wouldn't work. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Guests}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource GuestTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: What's the difference in setting the `ItemTemplate` to a `DynamicResource`, and using `DataType` in `DataTemplates` for `Room` and `Guest`?

Comment: @Bob. The difference is that if you set the `ItemTemplate`, all your items in a given `ListBox` or `ItemsControl` will have that same Template, whereas using `DataTemplate.DataType` lets WPF take care of finding the appropiate template for each item, thus allowing different templates in the same ListBox / ItemsControl.

Comment: Are there situations where you'd use one over the other? If you know the `ListBox` will have `Type A` objects should you still specify that you should use the `Type A Template` in the `ItemTemplate` versus having the `DataTemplate` inside `ListBox.Resources`? Then have `Type B Template` inside `ListBox.Resources` and having WPF resolve the `DataType` itself?